# Determine the angles of quadrilateral that make it concyclic

Tags: geometry, optimization, analytic-geometry, quadrilateral

Inspired by a [recent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4868427/can-i-determine-the-angles-of-a-quadrilateral-if-i-know-the-lengths-of-the-sides), consider the following problem.  You are given the four sides lengths of a quadrilateral $ABCD$.  Let these sides be $a = AB , b = BC, c = CD, d = DA $.  I want to determine the angles $ \phi = \angle DAB $ and $\theta = \angle ABC $, that will make this quadrilateral concyclic (i.e. having its vertices on a single circle).  That is the task.  As a hint, from [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral) we know that such a quadrilateral maximizes the area $[ABCD]$ of the quadrilateral.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

COMMENT.-It is easy if we take into account that the opposite to the angle in a vertex must be its suplement. In fact
$$\overline{DB}^2=a^2+d^2-2ad\cos(\phi)=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos(\pi-\phi)=b^2+c^2+2bc\cos(\phi)$$ so
$$\cos(\phi)=\frac{a^2+d^2-(b^2+c^2)}{2(ad+bc)}$$Similarly with the other angle.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's true.  How could I miss that?